# Pesky audio popping on Dell laptop, even after replacing parts and reinstalling

Tags: audio, troubleshooting

I have a problem with audio popping on my Dell laptop.  Audio has been the most affected.  I bet other things have been as well, but it is harder to tell.  It began a few months ago and I don't think Dell knows what the issue is.  VLC Media Player was giving me some sort of buffer error earlier, but I upgraded it and it is no longer doing it so I can't be more specific.  I replaced the motherboard and the hard-drive and reinstalled the OS.  Did I get more defective stuff or is something else the matter?  If the problem is with a different component, what component?

The problem seems to get worse when the computer gets busier.  For instance, I was using the Mixx DJ program and when I loaded a song into one deck while playing in the other it got really bad to the point where the song would just go out for long periods of time. When loading was completed and then went back to being more mild.  It is like my computer has lost all ability to multi-task and/or prioritize.

Some programs pop (Flash Player) and some skip forward after a second or 2 like the playback is slower than the timecode (VLC Media Player).  I don't think that my specs are necessary because my computer didn't use to do this so why would the answer be there.  The problem is always there, so listening to things on my computer is very irritating.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: no prob; hope i got that "replaced mobo/hdd" stuff right.  you only mentioned it in the title so i wasn't quite sure where in the narrative it fit.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you could be using the onboard soundcard? If this is the case then consider using third party drivers which lower latency: http://www.asio4all.com/

Also consider investing in an external USB soundcard.